# Pass variable to sed and change backslash to forward slash

Tags: sed

I am writing a bash script to mount DFS Windows shares via `cifs`. I have the main part working, but I am having trouble for when I need the user to enter the DFS path as a variable and convert the backslashes to forward slashes.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 FILE='\\edi3\welshch\test'

 FILEPATH="$("$FILE" | sed -e 's/\\/\//gp')"
 echo $FILEPATH
```

I had another script that used a command to find a filepath for AD home directories then piped to sed as per the part `| sed -e 's/\\/\//gp`

However this script above gives me;
`./test.sh: line 10: \\edi3\welshch\test: command not found`

Comment: You need to echo the variable to pipe it into the sed command

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes in your path: `FILE='\\\\edi3\\welshch\\test'`

Comment: @EnterUserNameHere when I echo it to pipe it displays it twice

Comment: @Panki I cannot escape the backslashes as they will be entered as the DFS file path by the user as a variable in the final script

Comment: The error you've provided mentions "line 10", but your script is only 6 lines long.  Perhaps the "displaying it twice" is due to some part of the script that you've not included in the question?

Comment: @Panki, that's inside single quotes, backslashes aren't special there. Try it: `FILE='\\\\edi3\\welshch\\test'; echo "$FILE"`

Comment: @ilkkachu returns `\\edi3\welshch\test` for me

Comment: @Panki, right, [using `echo` there was my mistake](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo). Try with `printf "%s\n" "$FILE"` instead. Or something like `foo='\\\\'; echo "${#foo}"` (gives the length of the string).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inside the command substitution you have `"$FILE" | sed -e 's/\\/\//gp'`, which the shell expands to (the equivalent of) `'\\edi3\welshch\test' | sed -e 's/\\/\//gp'`. Since it's a *command*, the shell goes looking for a file called `\\edi3\welshch\test` to run.

You probably meant to use `echo "$FILE" | sed ...` to pass the contents of `FILE` to `sed` via the pipe.

Note that even that's not right, some versions of `echo` will process the backslashes as escape characters, messing things up. You'll need `printf "%s\n" "$FILE" | sed ...` for it to work in all shells. See: [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)

Also, note that the default behaviour of `sed` is to print the line after whatever operations it does. When you use `/p` on the `s///` command, it causes an additional print, so you get the result twice in the output.

That said, since you're using Bash, you could just use the string replacement expansion:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE='\\edi3\welshch\test'
FILEPATH=${FILE//\\//}
echo "$FILEPATH"
```

gives the output `//edi3/welshch/test`

Answer (score 2):

The variable has to be output (by echo) to sed. Using `sed -n` to suppress sed output. **Edit** - don't need `sed -n` if we omit the sed `p` flag.

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='\\edi3\welshch\test'

FILEPATH="$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\\/\//g')"
echo $FILEPATH
```

Comment: The `-n` counters the `p` -- why not remove both?  You could also save one backslash by using a different delimiter, eg `s_\\_/_g`.

Comment: @JigglyNaga good call, missed that. Post edited.

Answer (score 2):

To substitute individual characters, it's simpler to use [`tr`(1)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr):

```
FILE=$(echo "$FILE" | tr '\\' / )
```